# How to assign the specific SRAM area for a specific purpose

Tags: memory, variables

I want to assign the SRAM start address for a specific purpose like the following.

```
#define STATUS_TASK1 (*(volatile unsigned char *)(0x12000000))
#define STATUS_TASK2 (*(volatile unsigned char *)(0x12000001))
```

But after compiling and linking, this area is assigned to variables.

```
motor1_flag                             0x12000000   Data           3  main.o(.data) 
led_status                              0x12000003   Data           1  main.o(.data)
```

How can I assign the SRAM(0x12000000 ~ 0x12000001) for a specific purpose(using KEIL)?

Thanks